# Retrieve drawables from an int array

Tags: image, drawable

Is there a way I can get the drawable IDs from an int array that contains the list of drawable images? This is how I store them:

```
Integer[] imageIDs = {
        R.drawable.tssr_1,
        R.drawable.tssr_2,
        R.drawable.tssr_3,
        R.drawable.tssr_4,
        R.drawable.tssr_5,
        R.drawable.tssr_6                   
};
```

This is where I need it:

```
Drawable d = imageIDs[0];  // Type mismatch: cannot convert from Integer to Drawable
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)d).getBitmap();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should convert the drawable resource integer id to drawable object

```
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(imagesIDs[0]);
```

For more details, check it here [Resources|Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html)

If you purpose is converting drawable resource id to Bitmap:

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(),
            imageIDs[index]);
```